# argparse metavar for nargs='+' to get numbered arguments in help info?

Tags: python, argparse

In the [argparse document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html), there is an example using `nargs='+'`:

```
parser.add_argument('integers', metavar='N', type=int, nargs='+')
```

The corresponding help information is

```
usage: prog.py [-h] [--sum] N [N ...]
```

Is it possible to set the `metavar` such that the help info looks like this?

```
usage: prog.py [-h] [--sum] N1 [N2 ...]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`metavar` can be tuple, as in

```
In [26]: parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
In [27]: a=parser.add_argument('--integers', metavar=('N1','N2'), type=int, nargs='+');
In [28]: parser.print_help()
usage: ipython3 [-h] [--integers N1 [N2 ...]]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  --integers N1 [N2 ...]
```

But that only works for optionals (flagged arguments), not positionals. I'm not exactly sure why, though I may have dug into this issue before.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#metavar

---

With the positional, the error stack includes:

```
/usr/lib/python3.5/argparse.py in _format_action_invocation(self, action)
    542         if not action.option_strings:
    543             default = self._get_default_metavar_for_positional(action)
--> 544             metavar, = self._metavar_formatter(action, default)(1)
    545             return metavar
    546
```

A `positional` doesn't have `option_strings` (or its empty), so it's using the `metavar, = ...` unpacking idiom to ask for just one string.  Hence the error: `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 1)`.

So expecting only one `metavar` variable is quite intentional, but I'm not sure about the rational.  Maybe it's because it would be harder to tell where one positional ends and the next starts in the `usage`:

```
In [34]: parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
In [35]: parser.add_argument('foo', type=int, nargs=2);
In [36]: parser.add_argument('bar', type=int, nargs='+');
In [38]: parser.print_usage()
usage: ipython3 [-h] foo foo bar [bar ...]
```

I looked at this a couple of years ago, https://bugs.python.org/issue14074.  Looks like there can be problems with the `usage`, help-lines and error message.

---

Actually the problem isn't in the `usage`, it's in formatting the help lines:

```
In [39]: parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
In [40]: a=parser.add_argument('integers', metavar=('N1','N2'), type=int, nargs='+')
In [41]: parser.print_usage()
usage: ipython3 [-h] N1 [N2 ...]
```

The normal help line for a positional just shows one symbol, not the `N [N ...]` of the usage:

```
In [43]: parser.print_help()
usage: ipython3 [-h] N [N ...]

positional arguments:
  N
```

Answer (score 2):

I would make a custom `HelpFormatter` and use that.  Below is a quick hack.

```
from argparse import HelpFormatter, ZERO_OR_MORE, ONE_OR_MORE


class CustomHelpFormatter(HelpFormatter):
    def _format_args(self, action, default_metavar):
        get_metavar = self._metavar_formatter(action, default_metavar)
        if action.nargs == ZERO_OR_MORE:
            return '[%s1 [%s2 ...]]' % get_metavar(2)
        elif action.nargs == ONE_OR_MORE:
            return '%s1 [%s2 ...]' % get_metavar(2)
        else:
            return super()._format_args(action, default_metavar)


>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(formatter_class=CustomHelpFormatter)
>>> parser.add_argument('integers', metavar='N', type=int, nargs='+')
>>> parser.parse_args(['--help'])
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the HelpFormatter does not expose a public API, so subclassing and overriding the _format_args() method could easily be broken by future Python versions.